# Is it possible for Host OS (MacOS) to use VPN connection made by VM (VirtualBox) on Win10

Tags: macos, virtualbox, vpn, juniper

Background: I was trying to connect through VPN but it seems the client (Juniper Network Connect) can only be installed, configured and started through some Java applet on company's portal which I couldn't make work on MacOS (long list of reasons… applet ultimately breaks and support is pretty much useless).

Anyways, I've launched Win10 VM (VirtualBox) and used MS Edge browser to set up the connection. It works fine inside that VM.

Is there any way to make this VPN connection from Win10 VM available to the host OS (MacOS) so I could use MacOS going forward (ie. use MacOS native software to work instead of installing/using equivalent tools for Win inside that VM)?